# To remove :ss part from WebDataRocks "time" JSON type

Tags: javascript, webdatarocks

[image]

I only need to use hours and minutes parts. How to use "time" JSON type without as `:ss`?

[Web Data Rocks JSON types](https://www.webdatarocks.com/doc/data-types-in-json/)

["time" data type usage example which is referred from above document page.](https://codepen.io/webdatarocks/pen/eLagqo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved the issue by using customizeCell method,

```
function customizeCellFunction(cellBuilder, cellData){
  if(cellData && 
     cellData.hierarchy && 
     cellData.hierarchy.uniqueName==="Duration"     
  ){    
    cellBuilder.text = cellBuilder.text.slice(0,-3)  // HH:MM:ss => HH:MM 
  }
}
```

Codepen link : https://codepen.io/AKCAK/pen/KKgXVwp?editors=0010